# alone in a CoinJoin amongst colluding scoundrels- can they spot you?

Tags: coinjoin

What if you participate in a CoinJoin and all the other actors that you're exchanging with are colluding against you, or controlled by the same person.

I guess in this scenario if they wanted they could easily identify you, isn't that right?

Comment: What do you mean with "identify you"? Obviously, they'll be able to identify your inputs and your outputs if they provide the remaining. Is that your question?

Comment: so then there is no way to prevent against that from happening? is that a feasible attack?